# Initialize array of non default constructible objects of template argument length

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to construct an array of non default constructible objects of `numObjects` length where `numObjects` is a template argument? For example...

```
struct NonDefaultConstructibleClass
{
    NonDefaultConstructibleClass(int){}
};

template<size_t numObjects>
struct Thing
{
    Thing() : m_Objects{{3, 3, 3, /*... numObjects times */}} {}

    NonDefaultConstructibleClass m_Objects[numObjects];
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize std::array<T, n> elegantly if T is not default constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497122/how-to-initialize-stdarrayt-n-elegantly-if-t-is-not-default-constructible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor of `Thing`, you can create a parameter pack with `N` elements, and forward the construction to a variadic constructor. The variadic constructor initializes the array with regular parameter expansion.

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct Thing
{
    NonDefaultConstructibleClass _elements[N];
    Thing() : Thing{build_indexes<N>{}} { }
    template <std::size_t... Indexes>
    Thing(indexes<Indexes...>)
        : _elements{(Indexes, 3)...}
    { }
};
```

`indexes` and `build_indexes` are simple helper classes. C++14 will most likely contain something similar (`std::integer_sequence`). In GCC you can use the following type aliases:

```
template <std::size_t ...Indexes>
using indexes = std::_Index_tuple<Indexes...>;

template <std::size_t N>
using build_indexes = typename std::_Build_index_tuple<N>::_type;
```

Comment: If the array is a `std::array` you do not even have to constructor forward: just call a helper fumction.  This is useful if your compiler lacks support for forwarding ctors, or if you find the extra ctor distracting.