# How to initialize an std::array<T, 2> where T is non-copyable and non-default-constructible?

Tags: c++

I have a fixed number of objects of class T that are non-copyable and non-default-constructible. Since the size is fixed I would like to use an array-ish container like `std::array` instead of `unique_ptr` or `vector`. I would like to avoid the additional layer of indirection if I can help it.

How do I initialize an `std::array<T, 2>`? Using `array<T, 2> {T(...), T(...)}` results in an error about deleted copy constructor. Using `array<T, 2> {move(T(...)), move(T(...))}` does not force the array elements to use the move constructor. If `std::array<T, 2>` inherently does not work, what else can I do without resorting to an additional layer of indirection or manual memory management techniques like placement-new?

Comment: Sounds to me like all instances of T should be accessed only via smart pointers. `std::array` of unique/shared ptrs to T, etc...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Yet you can use `std::vector` with move-only, non-default-constructible types just fine.

Comment: What I want to accomplish can in-principle be accomplished, albeit with messy and hard-to-read techniques like placement new. I know a vector would be simple but it gives me the additional overhead that I set out to avoid that in-principle is completely avoidable.

Comment: Have you considered using a tuple?

Comment: I want to access the elements with an index.

Comment: Somewhat related: [constructor - Inlining an array of non-default constructible objects in a C++ class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707923/inlining-an-array-of-non-default-constructible-objects-in-a-c-class)

Answer (score 5):

No need for extra stuff, just initialize it directly:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(int,char) {}

    Foo(Foo const &) = delete;
    Foo & operator = (Foo const &) = delete;
};
```

```
    std::array<Foo, 2> arr {{ {1, '1'}, {2, '2'} }};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a984c02f42c6839)

Comment: LOL one more set of braces... that's what I forgot. +1.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Where can I got to learn the meaning of these layers of braces for the std::array?

Comment: @JoshuaChia [stl - Why is the C++ initializer_list behavior for std::vector and std::array different? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/why-is-the-c-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-differen)

Answer (score 0):

My example is not the best but it works.. Just create a function that `make_array` and have it create the instances for you..

http://ideone.com/fxAO3t

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int)
        {

        }

        Foo(const Foo &) = delete;

        Foo(Foo &&)
        {
            std::cout<<"Moved\n";
        }
};

template<class... Type>
constexpr std::array<typename std::common_type<Type...>::type, sizeof...(Type)> make_array(Type&&... t)
{
    return {std::forward<Type>(t)...};
}

int main() {
    auto arr = make_array(Foo{1}, Foo{2});
    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can do `std::array<Foo, 2> arr = {Foo{1}, Foo{2}}`.

I noticed you were trying to `move` in your post. Are you sure your class is `moveable`?

Comment: If `Foo` is moveable, you don't need the function. Just `std::array<Foo, 2> arr{1, 2};` is sufficient.

Comment: Ahh you're right. OP was trying to do exactly what you just suggested. He/She was doing `std::move(Foo)`.